# Adding large range of values to dictionary if criteria is satisfied

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to add a large range (D:AX) to a dictionary based upon a key in column L starting at row 5 to the first blank cell in L.  The code is currently setup to grab values from column L and AX.  How do I modify this code to add values D:AX into the dictionary using L as the key?  Any help is appreciated!

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreatObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row > 5 Then If .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row > 5 Then last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row Else last = 5 Else last = 5
    Set rData = .Range("L5:L" & last & ",AX5:AX" & last)
    For i = rData.Row To rData.Row + rData.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not .Cells(i, "L").Value = "" Then If Not dict.Exists(.Cells(i, "L").Value) Then dict(.Cells(i, "L").Value) = .Cells(i, "AX").Value


    Next i
    .Parent.Close False
End With
```

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` on top. Thus, errors like `CreatObject` would be avoided immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim last As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row > 5 Then
            last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        Else
            last = 5
        End If

        Dim rData As Range

        Set rData = .Range("L5:L" & last & ",AX5:AX" & last)

        Dim i As Long

        For i = rData.Row To rData.Row + rData.Rows.Count - 1

            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "L")) And Not dict.Exists(.Cells(i, "L").Value) Then

                dict.Add .Cells(i, "L").Value, .Range(.Cells(i, "d"), .Cells(i, "AX"))

            End If

        Next i
        ' .Parent.Close False

    End With

   Dim key As Variant
   Dim counter As Long

   For Each key In dict.keys

      counter = counter + 1

      Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & counter).Resize(dict.Count, dict(key).Columns.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict(key))

   Next key

End Sub
```

And if storing values as array rather than range

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim last As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row > 5 Then
            last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        Else
            last = 5
        End If

        Dim rData As Range

        Set rData = .Range("L5:L" & last & ",AX5:AX" & last)

        Dim i As Long

        For i = rData.Row To rData.Row + rData.Rows.Count - 1

            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "L")) And Not dict.Exists(.Cells(i, "L").Value) Then

                dict.Add .Cells(i, "L").Value, .Range(.Cells(i, "D"), .Cells(i, "AX")).Value

            End If

        Next i
        ' .Parent.Close False

    Dim columnCount As Long
    columnCount = .Range(.Cells(i, "D"), .Cells(i, "AX")).Columns.Count

    End With

   Dim key As Variant
   Dim counter As Long

   For Each key In dict.keys
       counter = counter + 1
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & counter).Resize(1, columnCount) = dict(key)
   Next key

End Sub
```

Writing out to txt file:

```
 Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\Test.txt", True, True)
    Dim n As Long

    For Each key In dict.keys

        For n = 1 To UBound(dict(key), 2)
          Fileout.WriteLine dict(key)(1, n)
        Next n

    Next key

    Fileout.Close
```

Comment: The code seems to work thus far.  As a last step I am trying to paste the dictionary into a text file using the code below.              FilePath = path & "\OrderStatus.txt"

    'Open the text file
    Close #1
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    
    With OrderStatus
        For Each ky In .keys
            Write #1, ky & "," & OrderStatus(ky)
        Next ky
    End With

Comment: Did that make sense?

Comment: I am getting an error #13 Type mismatch on the ubound line.

Comment: The text file code is to go with the array version of the former code I.e. the second version

Comment: Are you using it with the array version? i.e. the bottom one?